# Changing instance variables from another class C#

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, class, instance-variables

I have a form "Main" and a form "Prices". The Main class has a Ingredient subclass, and instances of that subclass are initialized in the Main constructor. The Main form launches the Prices form after a button is pressed. The Prices form has a few text boxes and a button.

The problem is that I want to modify variables of instances of the Ingredient subclass by using fresh input data from the Prices form. I realize that passing those variables to the Prices form can be easily done through the constructor arguments, however, I can't figure out how to pass those modified variables back to the Main class as I'll need them there after I'll will close the Prices form.

Main class

```
public partial class Main : Form
{
    public class Ingredient
    {
        public string name;
        public  int weight;
        public  int price;
        public  int energy;
        public  int tmp;

        public Ingredient(string mName, int mWeight, int mPrice, int mEnergy)
        {

            name = mName;
            weight = mWeight;
            price = mPrice;
            energy = mEnergy;
        }
    }


    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Ingredient hazulnuts = new Ingredient("hazulnuts", 0, 0, 0);        
    }


    private void bEditPrices_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // I could pass variables of the Ingredients instance here through the constructor,
        // but haven't done so yet because I'm hoping there is some way that I can directly
        // access variables of instances of Ingredient class as there could be quite a lot 
        //of these instances
        Prices prices = new Prices();
        prices.Show();
        // The Main form is hidden when the Prices form is shown, therefore instantiating a new 
        //Main from the Prices isn't an option
        this.Hide();
    }

}
```

Prices class:

```
public partial class Prices : Form
{

    public Prices()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    // retrieve values of textboxes somehow pass the variables back to the
    // Main form's Ingredient instances

     //I realize that the code below is not syntactically correct but I'm looking 
     //for something along of the lines of that.
        this.Close;
        Main.show();
    }


}
```

Comment: Maybe when you construct your Prices form `Prices prices = new Prices();`, you could pass the instance of the parent to the child's constructor. (e.g. `this` keyword).  Then you will have access to the parent's public members from the child form.

Comment: How are you storing this information? I assume you are storing this data to a database or to a file or something? If so, your 'Prices' form should save the data somewhere when the form closes, than your `Ingredient` class should just have a method called `RefreshPrices()` and that method  should load the new prices from the database or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe when you construct your Prices form Prices prices = new Prices();, you could pass the instance of the parent to the child's constructor. (e.g. this keyword). Then you will have access to the parent's public members from the child form.  For example

```
public partial class Prices : Form
{
    private Main _parent;

    public Prices(Main parent)
    {
        this._parent = parent;
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this._parent.Name = "HelloWorld";
    }
}
```

And from Main you construct the Prices form as:

```
Prices prices = new Prices(this);
```

Just be aware of the model of control at play here, and try to keep consistent across the application

Answer (score 0):

Define your instance of Ingredient in the Main class as public, and pass a reference to the Main class to Prices.

```
public partial class Main : Form
{
    public Ingredient Hazulnuts { get; set; }


    private void bEditPrices_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Prices prices = new Prices(this);
        prices.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
}


public partial class Prices : Form
{
    private Main _mainForm;
    private Prices()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public Prices(Main mainForm) : Prices()
    {
        _mainForm = mainForm;

    }

    private void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _mainform.Hazulnuts = //

    }
}
```